# Will there be a proposal for every SO-tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51

- [Symfony](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15075/symfony) vs. [842 questions tagged symfony* at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony~)
- [cocos2d](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15013/cocos2d) vs. [342 questions tagged cocos2d at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d) and [1 question (yay!) at GameDev Beta](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d)
- [Maven](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14758/maven) vs. [2k questions tagged maven* at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven~)

to name three recent ones... shall we just give them their chance or close as dupes?

---

Feature-request: for new proposals do an automatic search for related tags at SOFU showing the current question count.

Comment: I'm holding out for a proposal for a Stack Exchange site on "strings".

Comment: I'm holding out for a proposal on proposals.

Comment: @Rosinante - I recently proposed to propose that on another proposal, but it was met with a strong counter proposal and closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm holding out for a proposal on things tagged `*friday*`.

Comment: (For once, the pared-down comment Markdown works in my favor!)

Comment: @Grace: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15122/strings